# tracking the parent

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

fellow coders, the following is a snippet of the structure i am working on. I have a list of items (the-list) that contains a bunch of items each identified by wrapper with an id with a value unique to that item (id="123"). Each item has a bunch of descendent elements including one holding some action buttons.

```
<div id="the-list">

    <div id="123" class="an-item">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="something"></div>
            <div id="actions">
                <botton id="action-email">email</button>
                <botton id="action-edit">edit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="124" class="an-item">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="something"></div>
            <div id="actions">
                <botton id="action-email">email</button>
                <botton id="action-edit">edit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>  

</div>
```

I'm handling the bubbling mouse clicks at the list (the-list) level and that seems to be working. My problem is being able to identify which item's button was clicked. so when one of the email action button is clicked I need to know whether it was the one belonging to item 123 or item 124.

Is there a way to get the parent id number through jQuery or a better design pattern?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You may not use the same ID twice!**

Give your button separate IDs - in this case you can just use the IDs to identify the buttons - or classes. In this case you can get the parent it using this code; assuming `this` is the button: `$(this).closest('.an-item').attr('id')`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/SvBR2/

Comment: Nice one! i really screwed up big time typing my example. maybe <botton> will be introduced in html6 ;) as for the multiple id, duh! no excuses there. your suggestion and that of Drackir work well. i also thought about a couple of other solutions: A) after cleaning up the html from multiple ids, in my click event handler i can use `$(e.target).parents(".list-item");` to grab the parent of the clicked button since there is only one element (parent) with the .list-tem class. i forgot that parents() takes a selector as a parameter. Or B)....

Comment: ...wrap the <button>s in a div and use a custom attribute say "action-on-item-id" with the item's id value (123). this can be retrieved like so: `$(e.target).parent().attr("action-on-item-id"));`. Not sure which solution is better. any thoughts on custom attributes?

Comment: @djtee: If you're going to use custom attributes, use [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) (ie. `<tag data-myattrname="" />`), then you can use jQuery's `.data()` function to retrieve it. This is also HTML5 compatible and will allow your site to pass validations.

Comment: hmmm, didn't know they were added to html5. should pay more attention in class ;) thanks for the link. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you spelled "button" incorrectly in your example code. You should fix that. :)

Secondly, as ThiefMaster said, you have to give the buttons unique ID's. Two elements can have the same `name` attribute, but not the same `id` attribute. This goes for all of your elements. You probably want to give them classes if it's not necessary to have their unique IDs.

Then, once you've done that. Using your click event at the list level, you can get the ID of the clicked button like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('#the-list').click(function(evt) {
        var elemid = $(evt.target).attr('id');
        if (/action-/.test(elemid)) {
            alert('this is an action! Element ID: ' + elemid);
        }
    });
});
```

This also tests to make sure a button was pressed by doing a regex check on the id to make sure it has "action-" in it. This just makes sure that you're not clicking on some other element instead of a button.

You can see this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Drackir/jVLFb/3/).